# NSFileManager is not deleting files in temporary folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am using an app that downloads images from the internet and caches them for faster performance as a user swipes back and forth between the images.

I would like to clear out the cache folder when the UIViewController is dismissed. So I created this static method. However, I keep getting the error: **"File could NOT be deleted**" on every file.

The `sDocumentsDir` is

*/Users/MyName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E5FAB592-143A-4B04-9A8C-CFEA73E6C712/data/Containers/Data/Application/2EB9CB73-9D34-4CE4-BA91-E9A3F2FC1CFA/Documents/.tmp*

The filenames look like this:

*https___s3.amazonaws.com_mycompany_1288c8be6f8101.jpg*

***What am I doing wrong?***

```
+ (BOOL) clearCacheFolder {
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *sDocumentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    sDocumentsDir = [sDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/.tmp"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension == 'png' || pathExtension == 'jpg'"];

    BOOL isDir;
    if(([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:sDocumentsDir isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir)) {

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *fileArr = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sDocumentsDir error:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"clearCacheFolder error populating array");
            return false;
        }

        NSLog(@"clearCacheFolder number of items to delete: %lu, files: %@",fileArr.count, fileArr.description);

        for(NSString *file in [fileArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]){

            @try {
                [filemgr removeItemAtPath:[sDocumentsDir stringByAppendingString:file] error:&error];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"File delete exception: %@", exception.description);
            } @finally {
                if(error){
                    NSLog(@"File could NOT be deleted");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"File Deleted");
                }
            }
        }

        fileArr = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sDocumentsDir error:&error];
        NSLog(@"clearCacheFolder FINISHED count: %lu",fileArr.count);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You've tested `error` for being not `nil` but your code does not appear to display what `error` is - that would probably help yo, add it to your `NSLog`

Comment: 1. Try to use cache folder instead of documents

Comment: 2. Of you are using cache only for short time while VC is presented, I will advice you to create directory for it (you can name it after vc.hash as it is unique) and the whole content of the folder, instead of complicated filter.

Comment: @CRD (and OP): You should never check for the error object before checking for the return value: *Important: Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the method. Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the method indicates failure by directly returning nil or NO, you should always check that the return value is nil or NO before attempting to do anything with the NSError object.* I. e. the code will probably break if you have a handled error in advance.

Comment: Moreover, the `@try`… is not very Cocoa'ish. Please read something about error handling in Cocoa. This and CRD's hint will help.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov any tutorials on using a cache folder or the vc.hash?

Comment: @user-44651 Regarding caches you can start from : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW11 Regarding hash - just common sense - hash is should-be-unique identifier used to distinguish objects. Means that any VC will have unique hash, seems it's what you need. You can clean them intentionally when you need, and system will clean any unused caches or tmp files time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Check filepath You trying to use.
`[sDocumentsDir stringByAppendingString:file]` will produce wrong filepath.
In Your example it will look like
/Users/MyName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E5FAB592-143A-4B04-9A8C-CFEA73E6C712/data/Containers/Data/Application/2EB9CB73-9D34-4CE4-BA91-E9A3F2FC1CFA/Documents/.tmphttps___s3.amazonaws.com_mycompany_1288c8be6f8101.jpg